# No memory available on my iPhone 6?

Tags: memory, iphone

I don't understand why I can't save or take photo or video in my iPhone 6. I have 32GB and my photo gallery is empty. I did not install anything for example games and other app. When I record a video, appears a notice "full memory". I have just restart my iPhone 6 but it remains like before.

Comment: Will you go check your storage settings as to what takes space on the iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings -> General -> Storage & iCloud Usage -> Manage Storage.

It will show you **Used** and **Available** Space on your iPhone.

[image]